# State of privacy-preserving light clients

Tags: client, privacy, spv

Currently, it is trivial to operate a SPV wallet in Bitcoin at the cost of a lot of privacy due to the necessity to connect to full nodes that offer SPV services.

[Neutrino](https://github.com/lightninglabs/neutrino), currently being worked on by the lightninglabs team is one of the few privacy-preserving light clients in Bitcoin. But how does it work?

What theoretical solutions exist that can solve SPV privacy problems?